# How to play music in the background in an android app?

Tags: java, android, service, background

I want in my application, music playing regardless of what happening in application. I am trying to implement it with `Service`. Here is the **MyService.class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme_song);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Could you please help me about how I use `Service` in MyActivity and what other methods need to be defined in **MyService.class** to have the right result.

Comment: Do you want to play music through out your application in background?

Comment: Check this link http://sapandiwakar.in/building-a-music-player-app-for-android-2/

Comment: I want only when GUI is active.

Comment: Thanks Amee Joshi i will check the article.It seems usefull.

Comment: @SakisPaligiannis check below code by using media player methods  which i mention in service you can start,stop, pause and resume music from anywhere in your app. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class BackGroundMusic extends Service {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    int volume;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tune);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {

        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;

    }
}
```

and if You need to play the music

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackGroundMusic.class))
```

if you want to stop the music

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackGroundMusic.class))..
```

Comment: Is this code complete? Because I get "never used" on `Audiomanager "audiomanager";` and `int "volume";`

Comment: int origionalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);       you can use the above code for use your AudioManager to set Volume

Comment: @FisnikB. Use Above Code.. Initialize the volume.. Now use your volume and reset into the initialized one

Comment: @Mr.Popular. I'm very thankful for the help but I honestly still don't get it. Don't know how to set this up. I'm new to android and been bugged by this for almost a week without managing to sort it out! Need this for my project which is deadline tomorrow. Any chance to put more details where to put what? Or if possible maybe send me "exact" code to just copy paste? Could give you my email. I would much, much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Make Background service

```
package service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import java.io.IOException;


public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    private final static int MAX_VOLUME = 100;
    Context context;
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int musicflag = (int) intent.getExtras().get("songindex");
        if (musicflag == 1) {
            playMusic(R.raw.s1_pondambience);
        } else {
            playMusic(R.raw.s2_integrative_music);
        }
        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        stopSelf();
    }

    /*
    * playmusic custom method for manage two different background sounds for application
    * */

    public void playMusic(int musicFile) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                try {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    mPlayer.release();
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicFile);

                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                        // Start playback.
                        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                        final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 85) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                        mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicFile);

                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                        // Start playback.
                        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                        final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 85) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                        mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } else {
            try {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicFile);

                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    // Start playback.
                    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 85) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
                    mPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
                    mPlayer.start();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * MediaPlayer methods
    * */

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and start and stop service whenever you want.

### 2. To Start Service use below method

```
 private void startBackMusic() {
        Intent musicintent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        musicintent.putExtra(EXTRA_SONGINDEX, 1);
        startService(musicintent);
    }
```

### 3. To Stop Service use below method

```
 private void stopBackMusic() {
          Intent musicintent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
            stopService(musicintent);
    }
```