# My program stop responding after I press a play button

Tags: java, android

So I created a small app with a play and a stop button. When I press the play button it should loop until I press the stop button. The problem is, once I press the play button, I can't do anything else and the stop button is not responsive. If I try to press the stop button my app says app doesn't respond and quit. I don't know why this is happening and I'm super new to Android and Java so this is a bit complicated for me to know why it doesn't work. Here is my actual code :

Play and stop method :

```
   public void play() {
    playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (buttonArray[i].isChecked()) {
                sp.play(snareId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            }
            if (!playing) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if(i == 3) i = -1;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void stop(){

    playing = false;//
}
```

Main activity

```
 playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mySample.play();
        }
    });

    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mySample.stop();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked the Exception e value while debugging? It should give you info related to the error.

Comment: The Exception e seems to give me those errors :"Thread[3,tid=10357,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xee65dc00,peer=0x16000020,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3" and :"Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Answer (score 1):

According Android [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#diagnosing_anrs), there are some common patterns to look for when diagnosing ANRs:

1. The app is doing slow operations involving I/O on the main thread.
2. The app is doing a long calculation on the main thread.
3. The main thread is doing a synchronous binder call to another
   process, and that other process is taking a long time to return.

   And others.

You are in situation number 2 because you create an infinite loop `while(playing)` in main thread (it's UI thread in this case). Just listen to changes from check boxes and do your task respectively.

```
public void play(){
   //call startService to play sound
   //for each toggle button
   buttonArray[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if (isChecked) {
            //do your tasks
          } else {
            //do your tasks
          }
       }
   });
}

public void stop(){
    //call stopService to play sound
    //for each toogle button:
    buttonArray[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
}
```

Comment: But I added a condition where I can manually stop the infinite loop isn't that enough?. How can I solve the problem while keeping my infinite loop?

Comment: Are buttonArray[i] checkboxes?

Comment: They are Toggle Buttons that are either checked or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I tried your solution but the problem in your solution is that the sound is only played when I press the toggle buttons but my goal is to play the sounds when I press the play button only. It seems the play and stop button become irrelevant in your solution.

Comment: @MichelPinto for playing sound, you should use `Service`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41222834/8531215